# How to cluster by sequence and return cluster sizes in R?

Tags: r

I'm very unfamiliar with many of the R packages out there, so I apologise for my poor googling skill if this has been solved elsewhere.

I am trying to group character sequences by their hamming distance and return the group sizes. Hamming distance is defined as the number of character difference required to change seqA into SeqB. For example, I have the following sequences:

```
[1] "24 sequences with ID 64"
[1] "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64" "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64"
[3] "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64" "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64"
[5] "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64" "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64"
[7] "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64" "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64"
[9] "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64" "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64"
[11] "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64" "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64"
[13] "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64" "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64"
[15] "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64" "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64"
[17] "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64" "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64"
[19] "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64" "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64"
[21] "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64" "   AAAAAACAAAGAACC 64"
[23] "   AAAAAAAAAAACTAT 64" "   AAAAATGCGTGTATA 64"
```

I know that there are three groups unique sequences here, their hamming distances are:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    6    8
[2,]    6    0   10
[3,]    8   10    0
```

Given that all three sequences differ in distance by more than 2 (positions required to change for a sequence A to look like sequence B), I will consider there to remain three unique sets of sequences.

If I had a group of sequences who hamming distances looked like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2   13
[2,]    2    0   13
[3,]   13   13    0
```

I would say that group 1 & 2 are in fact the same as they meet the <= 2 distance threshold, and group 3 is a unique group on its own. I would therefore, like to see an output somewhere along the lines of:

```
sum(group1,group2) 
sum(group3)
```

I can work out on pen and paper how to do this. But with my lack of experience in R, I have no idea where to being. Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: as common people don't know what a hamming distance is, you should explicit what your code needs to do and use dput to give your example, or wait for someone from your field to help you

Comment: Added a short definition. I'll add more after my commute.

Comment: I've updated my answer, if it's not answering your question, consider clarifying it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get everything you are looking for but here a script that may help you.

I made a script to build the groups and output a list.  It's not super pretty and may be hard to understand for a R beginner but that was the easier way I found:

```
make.groupe <- function(the_mat, min_dist = 2) {

  # prepare the result list
  res <- NULL

  # 1 member group:
  res <- as.list(rownames(the_mat)[apply(the_mat,1, function(xx) all(xx>min_dist | xx==0, na.rm=T) )])

  # 2 members group:
  the_mat[upper.tri(the_mat, diag = F)] <- NA

  library(reshape2)
  group <- subset(melt(the_mat), value!=0)
  group <- group[group$value <= min_dist,1:2]

  res <- unname(append(res, lapply(apply(unname(as.matrix(group)),1,as.list),unlist)))

  res
}
```

You give the function your matrix and the minimum distance:

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(0,2,13,2,0,13,13,13,0),3,3, dimnames = list(c("g1","g2","g3"),c("g1","g2","g3")))
make.groupe(mat1, 2)
[[1]]
[1] "g3"

[[2]]
[1] "g2" "g1"
```

Works with your first matrix as well:

```
mat2 <- matrix(c(0,6,8,6,0,8,8,10,0),3,3, dimnames = list(c("g1","g2","g3"),c("g1","g2","g3")))
make.groupe(mat2, 2)
[[1]]
[1] "g1"

[[2]]
[1] "g2"

[[3]]
[1] "g3"
```

If you change the minimum distance, it works:

```
mat2 <- matrix(c(0,6,8,6,0,8,8,10,0),3,3, dimnames = list(c("g1","g2","g3"),c("g1","g2","g3")))
make.groupe(mat2, 6)
[[1]]
[1] "g3"

[[2]]
[1] "g2" "g1"
```

Larger matrices works as well:

```
mat3 <- matrix(c(0,2,8,9,2,0,7,8,8,7,0,1,9,8,1,0),4,4, dimnames = list(c("g1","g2","g3","g4"),c("g1","g2","g3","g4")))
make.groupe(mat3, 2)
[[1]]
[1] "g2" "g1"

[[2]]
[1] "g4" "g3"
```

Were it doesn't work is for groups of 3 or more.

Another option, however it won't produce a list, is tu use clustering function:

```
cutree(hclust(as.dist(mat1)), h=2)
```

where h is the minimum distance.  This produce a vector where similar index represent the same group:

```
cutree(hclust(as.dist(mat1)), h=2)
g1 g2 g3 
 1  1  2 
cutree(hclust(as.dist(mat3)), h=2)
g1 g2 g3 g4 
 1  1  2  2 
cutree(hclust(as.dist(mat2)), h=2)
g1 g2 g3 
 1  2  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all that information. When I get back to this area of my code I'll see where your answer takes me.